# Getting the average grade from multiple subjects

Tags: php, laravel

So I have a game where a user has a grade in each subject and I want to get the overall grade when taking all current grades in to account..

So the subjects are: English, Science, ICT, Maths, Mechanics

And the grades are: A*, A, B, C, D, E, U.

Now for example each grade has an XP_NEEDED column, this column is known as the ending XP in the between and how I get the starting XP is the ending XP for the previous grade.

For example: U is 100XP, E is 200 XP, D is 500 XP, C is 1000 XP, B is 2000 XP, A is 3200 XP and A* is 4500 XP.

Possible outcomes:

If they had an A* and 4 U's, the overall grade would be around E

If they had 5 A*'s it would be A*

What is the best way to do this in PHP&Laravel 5.2? I havent tried anything yet because I dont have a clue where to start, and google doesnt help me at all.

Comment: `( 3200+(4*100) ) / 5 = 720` = the average which is a D grade, how did you get to an average E grade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you should have a way of allotting XP to each user for each subject and I am assuming that each user is taking all of those five subjects.

What you basically have to implement is the Average formula which in this case would be the *TotalXP(of all 5 subjects) divided by 5*. This result will give you the average XP of a certain user and based on your column, you can then assign them the respective grade.

I mean the total xp a user has earned. Which will be the sum of individual XPs earned in each subject.

Let's say a user has the following XPs: 2000, 3200, 3200, 4500, 1000. The TotalXP for this user will be: (2000 + 3200 + 3200 + 4500 + 1000) = 13900.
Now to get the AverageXP: (13900/5) = 2780.

You have your limits for the grades, using comparison, see in which range does the AverageXP lie. Now you can allot the Average Grade. In this case, 2780 is a B. 
(as 2000 < 2780 < 3200)

Comment: When you say the TotalXP of all 5 subjects, do you mean the users total xp all added together, or the xp_needed for the grade?